# Domain is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, html

I'm not really good with HTML, PHP, or other coding things. I really don't know how to make this work, but I made a submit form for my website. I did change the email already but I still get an error:

**the 'domain' is currently unable to handle this request.**

I got this code from here too and now I don't know what to do

THIS IS THE HTML FORM

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="share.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
    </div>
</div>

   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="category">Category</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
 <select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Student</option>
  <option value="">Parent</option>
  <option value="">School</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <! Will be used to display an alert to the user>
    </div>
</div>
```

THIS IS THE PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'IKB FORM'; 
    $to = 'EMAIL'; 
    $subject = 'Importante Ka Ba User ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'],    FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    if (!$_POST['category'] {
        $errCategory = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 5) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errCategory && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
       if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in    touch</div>';
}      else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the exact error? On what line did the error occur?

Comment: When I click on submit it shows that the domain is unable to handle the request, it says

The importantekaba.com page isn’t working

importantekaba.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: And it doesn't say what line the error occurs : (

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a closing parentheses `)` in the following if statement:

```
if (!$_POST['category'] {
```

change it to

```
if (!$_POST['category']) {
```

*If you have problems with scripts in the future make sure you enable error reporting. These error reports will provide a lot of information on what has happened and make debugging a lot easier. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/5914775) explains how you can enable it.*

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the typos!